# Laravel 9.x — Character encoding issue returning incorrect results for where() query

Tags: php, laravel, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

**BACKGROUND** — I'm creating an Arabic-English dictionary that uses transliterations as the unique identifiers for terms (e.g. to distinguish between أكل /ʔakl/ & أكل /ʔakal/). Many Arabic letters don't have Latin-script equivalents, so I use certain special characters like āēīōū, ṣḍṭẓ & so on.

I have the following query:

```
$asInflection = Inflection::where('translit', $term->slug);
```

I've just noticed that my use of special characters returns incorrect query results.

In one case, the **$term->slug** is **ʔamal** & there is an Inflection::where('translit', **ʔāmāl**). Laravel returns a match, which it should not; it's absolutely imperative for the dictionary's proper functioning that these characters not be treated the same. I'm not sure if the issue is with PHP or with MySQL; I'm pretty sure the issue nothing to do with Laravel itself, but I imagine there is something I can do via Laravel to solve it.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Probably due to a wrong _collation_ on the database / connection level.

Comment: Could you please share your DB structure along with collection?

Comment: `ʔ` is a "glottal stop", hex CA94 in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a character recognition problem from the Database.

if you want to match some speacial charcters then you should use `utf8_unicode_ci` type of Collation for `translit` type column instead of `utf8_general_ci`.

So here you need to replace column collation type from `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$asInflection = Inflection::where('translit', $term->slug)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`āēīōū, ṣḍṭẓ` can be represented in utf8mb4, which is the MySQL CHARACTER SET that you should be using.  `latin1` should not be used for Arabic.

```
select 'أكل /ʔakl/' = 'أكل /ʔakal/';
```

returns false (0).  And it only because of the last `a`.

`أكل /ʔakal/` is this in utf8mb4; here is the HEX() of it:

```
D8A3 D983 D984 2F CA94 61 6B 61 6C 2F
```

so I don't see the need for `āēīōū, ṣḍṭẓ`  Maybe it is the keyboard-entry that is lacking?

UNICODE is the controlling organization.  PHP, MySQL, Laravel, etc, simply follow its rules.  (I don't know about `Inflection`.)

Run this to see what collations you have.  I don't see any that are specific to Arabic:

```
SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';
```