# Encoding in Laravel 9.x — Validation fails due to incorrectly matching special characters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encoding, utf-8

[I previously asked a question about an encoding issue I was having in Laravel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947023/laravel-9-x-character-encoding-issue-returning-incorrect-results-for-where-q) Namely, my database query for **ʔamal** was returning **ʔāmāl** as a valid result — that is, the distinct characters **a** & **ā** were being interpreted as equivalent. It seems to have been an issue with the database table encoding. I was advised to change it to **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** & that seemed to work back then.

However, I'm still having a very similar issue — this time with validation. I'm creating a dictionary, so naturally the slug for each term's page should be unique. But now that I've created the word **mīn** the application isn't letting me create the word **min** (i.e. it does not consider **.../mīn** & **.../min** distinct). I've also just noticed for the first time that if, for example, I navigate to  **.../wēn** & manually change the address to **.../wen** (a non-existent word), it still displays the page for the term **wēn**.

Before even discussing encoding, is this somehow just a matter of browser behavior & so on? I mean, is there even a way to require my application to consider **.../mīn** & **.../min** distinct? If that's the case, could someone clarify how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ā` = `a` in virtually all utf8mb4 collations, even with the really old `utf8_general_ci`.

So, I claim, unless you use one of these, the a-macron will be treated by MySQL as equal to most other "a".

```
utf8_bin
utf8mb4_bin
utf8mb4_0900_as_ci   -- and any other %_as_% collation
```

`_bin` says to compare bits;
`_as_` means "accent sensitive"

In application code and in the browser, there are probably other rules.  They are probably treating `a` = `ā`.

**More**

To test a particular collation for a particular comparison:

```
SELECT 'a' = 'ā' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci;
```

Returning 1 means that they are treated equal; 0 if not.  Note:  This assumes that you are otherwise using the `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  There is also the `WEIGHT_STRING()` function.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure whether the collation would equate the two characters? I have tried applying these & unless I'm doing it wrong (which I might be) they aren't working.

Comment: @AdrianAbdul-Bahá - I added an example of how to see what s different collation (for the same charset) says about a string comparison.

Comment: See also `LENGTH()` versus `CHAR_LENGTH()`.